# Instagram Ruby tag likes getting TypeError

Tags: ruby, tags, instagram

I want to display the likes of each media a tag has.
I am getting the correct no. of likes in terminal , but the site returns an error:

TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum

file: base.rb location: + line: 96

```
 mtag = Instagram.tag_recent_media("tag")

 if mtag.has_key? "data"
    mtag.data.each do |media| 
      if media["likes"]["count"] > 0
        puts media["likes"]["count"]
      end
    end
 end
```

thanks a lot,

Eszter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks  media["likes"] is nil or media["likes"]["count"] is nil

Try:

```
if mtag.has_key? "data"
  mtag.data.each do |media| 
      puts "#{media['likes']}  <<< MEDIA LIKES"
  if media["likes"] &&  media["likes"]["count"]
      puts media["likes"]["count"]
    end
  end
end
```

What will it output?

Comment: thanks, this helps, but also needed to add: 
html << "#{media['likes']['count']} LIKES FOR <img src='#{media.images.thumbnail.url}'>" 
so sinatra renders the page as well.